# What should ESP.restart() exactly do in NodeMCU?

Tags: arduino-esp8266

What should `ESP.restart()` exactly do in NodeMCU? I want to redo my sketch, but after using `ESP.restart()` I'll get this in the terminal:

> ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(1,6)
>
> ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(1,6)
>
> wdt reset

And after that nothing happens. So how can I redo my sketch like using RST button of NodeMCU?

Comment: Maybe https://www.pieterverhees.nl/sparklesagarbage/esp8266/130-difference-between-esp-reset-and-esp-restart helps.

Comment: Thanx Marcel. problem was that after uploading sketch i didn't restart my NodeMCU.after restarting it, NodeMCU works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own problem:

A bug in ESP8266 is that after uploading sketch it needs to be restarted by `reset button` or be powered off and on, otherwise my problem will happen.

so the solution is restarting nodeMCU by `reset button` after uploading sketch

Answer (score 0):

I think ESP.restart() actually turns the device OFF and ON again i.e all your code would be ran all over again starting from the beginning.